# How many concurrent login allowed for API user?

Tags: api, integration

Building an ETL integration from 4-5 client machines connecting with salesforce using SINGLE API user account. Is there risk of multiple session login error? If not, how many concurrent sessions are allowed by salesforce? This is not load balancing/cluster environment but isolated machines running desktop application for Salesforce ETL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a limit of 3,600 logins per hour per user, but there's no technical limit to how many sessions you could theoretically be juggling at once. However, tying many clients to a single login makes it hard to identify the individual clients at the API level--if one of them goes haywire, you have no idea which one it was. <strike>Also, there are a few concurrent limits, such as the maximum number of cursors open at once (as noted in [Governor Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)</strike>) *(edit: [this is no longer a concern as of 56.0](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicursors.htm))*. All that said, you probably won't have any unusual problems using 4-5 clients at once, just remember that the more work you load on a single user account, the more likely you'll run into undesirable behavior.

Comment: It is often a struggle to get the business users to pay for 1 account to use for an API user, let alone multiple ones, though you have given plenty of  good arguments there for doing so.

Comment: @DaveHumm Yes, the struggle is real. And I agree, when you're first getting started, having a single API user is more than sufficient; I've even been with companies where the API user was just a system admin's account to save a license. Feel free to use as few licenses as you think you need, but just remember that there is some inherent risk in doing so.

Comment: Session management can do a lot to mitigate the logins per hour limit, depending on your architecture. We just ran into that.

Comment: Query cursor limit was removed in API 56.0 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicursors.htm

Comment: @ElkCor That's good to know, though there's still tons of reasons why one wouldn't want to share a login between integration users. There's also talk about a new api-only user that might be less expensive than a full license. It'll be interesting to hear more.

Answer (score 8):

I think the limiting technical factor will be the [Concurrent API Request Limit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm). For Dev and Sandbox orgs the current limit is 5. For production and Sandbox orgs the limit is 25.

Note that this limit only applies to requests running longer than 20 seconds.

It's worth thinking about the Total API Request Limits also mentioned on that page.

From past experience, don't call `logout()` from any of the sessions, as it will invalidate all the connections. If you look closely you will find that the session id will be the same on each client machine.

<strike>As @sfdcfox commented. You will also be limited to [10 API Query Cursors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicursors.htm). If you exceed this limit the oldest of the 10 is released. I.e. you won't be able to use it to retrieve further data.</strike> As @ElkCor commented, The [API Query Cursor Limit has been dropped](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicursors.htm).

Comment: Also, I'd suggest the possibility of QueryLocator cursors being dropped.

Comment: Query cursor limit was removed in API 56.0 
 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apicursors.htm